# Django Connection reset by peer 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: django, deployment, server, digital-ocean

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 30, 2020 - 23:18:31
Django version 3.0.2, using settings 'GroverLeagues.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[30/Jan/2020 23:18:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 0
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('<IP redacted>', 53076)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/lakepry/groverenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/lakepry/groverenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I'm deploying my first django application following Digitalocean's tutorial on deploying with postgresql database and it won't let me access my webpage in a browser. In the browser it says, "This site can't be reached". Port 8000 is allowed through the firewall as well. Any ideas on what to do?

edit: Here is the link to the tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Can you add a link to the tutorial that you are following and provide more information about the browser that you are trying to use and what your networking setup is (e.g. operating system, are you trying to access via localhost, IP or DNS, what firewalls you have)?

Comment: I added a link to the tutorial. It should answer your other questions as to what I did. I am failing at the "~/myprojectdir/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000" step right before appending "/admin" to the site.